# proving a linear transformation is normal operator

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm given that:

$$
T^2 = \frac{T+T^{*}}{2}
$$

over a inner product space, prove that T is a normal operator.
I've tried playing with it algebric and using the inner product space over 2 different vectors but didn't get anywhere. If anyone has an idea what's the way to solve this I would be very glad to hear it.

Answer (score 2):

Note that $T^*=2T^2-T,$ so
$$T^*T=(2T^2-T)T=2T^3-T^2=T(2T^2-T)=TT^*.$$

Comment: In essence, since $T^*$ is equal to $p(T)$ for some polynomial, it commutes with $T$.